# Seaborn Barplot and Formatting Dates on X-Axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I am currently working on visualizing datasets with Seaborn and Pandas. I have some time-dependent data that I would like to graph in bar charts.

However, I am battling with two issues in Seaborn:

1. Formatting dates on the x-axis
2. Only showing a handful of dates (as
   it doesn't make sense to have every day labeled on a 6 month graph)

I have found a solution for my issues in normal Matplotlib, which is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

N = 20
np.random.seed(2022)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=N, freq='m')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'dt':dates, 'val': np.random.randn(N)}
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
ax.bar(df['dt'], df['val'], width=25, align='center')
```

[image]

However, I already have most of my graphs done in Seaborn, and I would like to stay consistent. Once I convert the previous code into Seaborn, I lose the ability to format the dates:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

N = 20
np.random.seed(2022)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=N, freq='m')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'dt':dates, 'val': np.random.randn(N)}
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m'))
sns.barplot(x='dt', y='val', data=df)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

When I run the code, the date format remains unchanged and I can't locate any dates with DateLocator.

Is there any way for me to format my X-Axis for dates in Seaborn in a way similar to Matplotlib with DateLocator and DateFormatter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use `seaborn.barplot` in conjunction with `matplotlib.dates` ticking. The reason is that the ticks for seaborn barplots are at integer positions (0,1,..., N-1). So they cannot be interpreted as dates.

You have three options:

1. Use seaborn, and loop through the labels and set them to anything you want
2. Not use seaborn and have the advantages (and disadvantages) of `matplotlib.dates` tickers available.
3. Change the format in the dataframe prior to plotting.

- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.5.0`, `matplotlib 3.5.2`, `seaborn 0.12.0`**

```py
N = 20
np.random.seed(2022)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=N, freq='m')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'dates': dates, 'val': np.random.randn(N)})

# change the datetime format in the dataframe prior to plotting
df.dates = df.dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.barplot(x='dates', y='val', data=df)

xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xticklabels = [x.get_text() for x in ax.get_xticklabels()]

_ = ax.set_xticks(xticks, xticklabels, rotation=90)
```

[image]

```py
N = 20
np.random.seed(2022)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=N, freq='m')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'dates': dates, 'val': np.random.randn(N)})

df.dates = df.dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.barplot(x='dates', y='val', data=df)

xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xticklabels = [x.get_text() if not i%2 == 0 else '' for i, x in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels())]

_ = ax.set_xticks(xticks, xticklabels)
```

[image]