# Python seaborn, how to get xlabels formated as picture shows?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to show grouped bars chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(62918)
df_w = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.random.randint(15) for _ in range(50)],
                    'B': [np.random.randint(15) for _ in range(50)],
                    'dtime': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 08:00:00', freq='30T' ,periods=50)
                   })
df_l = df_w.melt(id_vars='dtime').sort_values('dtime')
```

df_l looks like:

[image]

Now I tried to plot it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))    
ax = sns.barplot(data = df_l, x = "dtime", y = 'value', ax=ax, hue='variable')
```

which resulted in plot like this one:

[image]

As you can see xlabels are useless.
How to transform xlabels to something like this?

[image]

For example there is a line for midnight, and tick for every 3 hours.
How to get this type of time on my xlabels?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638648/seaborn-barplot-and-formatting-dates-on-x-axis

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: If I use sns.lineplot(data = df_l, x = "dtime", y = 'value', ax=ax, hue='variable')
xtick_labels are OK

Answer (score 1):

It is usually more useful to visualize time series with lines rather than bars (especially when there are many data points like in your sample dataset), which maybe explains why both the pandas and seaborn bar plot functions do not automatically process datetime variables to create nice labels.

Assuming that you have good reasons to visualize your time series with bars rather than lines, the only option (to my knowledge; see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56638846/14148248)) is to manually create the labels you want. Here are two ways of doing this to match the format in your example. In both cases, the first time point is labeled with the time and the date, the rest of the labels depend on the time frequency of your choice.

Notice that I create the dataframe with the dtime variable as the index seeing as this makes it possible to create a pandas bar plot more conveniently than with seaborn and the result is nearly identical. If you decide to stick to seaborn, the solution for the labels remains the same.

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2

# Create a dataframe containing a random time series
np.random.seed(62918)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = [np.random.randint(15) for _ in range(50)],
                       B = [np.random.randint(15) for _ in range(50)]),
                  index = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 08:00:00',
                                        freq='30T', periods=50))

# Select time frequency parameters for ticks and ticklabels
obs_per_hour = 2 # because datetime freq='30T'
time_step_hour = 4 # frequency of ticks in terms of hours
time_step = obs_per_hour*time_step_hour

# Create pandas bar plot
# Note: by default pandas automatically draws all numerical columns
# contained in the df (here A and B) and uses the index for the x axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
df.plot.bar(ax=ax)

# Select ticks according to the selected time step
# Note: if the time step is not set to a factor of 8 (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8),
# which is the first time point of the date range, the midnight label
# that contains the date will not be visible
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(xticks[::time_step])

# Create custom tick labels by iterating through the timestamps of the
# df index using a list comprehension with an if-else statement to show
# date only when the day changes (first timestamp then every midnight)
# Format codes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes
xticklabels = [ts.strftime('%H:%M\n%d-%b') if ts.day != df.index.day[i-1]
               else ts.strftime('%H:%M') for i, ts in enumerate(df.index)]
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels[::time_step], rotation=0)

plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot_labels1]

If you would like to have the date label without necessarily having an hour label at midnight, here is another solution using the same dataset.

```
obs_per_hour = 2
time_step_hour = 6
time_step = obs_per_hour*time_step_hour

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
df.plot.bar(ax=ax)

# Create lists of ticks and labels depending on selected time step
custom_ticks = []
custom_labels = []
for idx in range(df.index.size):
    # Select ticks at time step and at midnights
    if idx%time_step == 0 or (df.index.minute[idx] == 0 and df.index.hour[idx] == 0):
        custom_ticks.append(idx)
    # Create labels showing hour:minutes and day-month at first timestamp
    # and at midnights when time step falls on midnights
    if idx == 0 or ((df.index.minute[idx] == 0 and df.index.hour[idx] == 0) and idx%time_step == 0):
        custom_labels.append(df.index[idx].strftime('%H:%M\n%d-%b'))
    # Create labels showing hour:minutes at each time step except at
    # midnights and at first timestamp
    if idx%time_step == 0 and not (df.index.minute[idx] == 0 and df.index.hour[idx] == 0) and not idx == 0:
        custom_labels.append(df.index[idx].strftime('%H:%M'))
    # Create labels showing day-month at midnights when time step does
    # not fall on midnights
    if (df.index.minute[idx] == 0 and df.index.hour[idx] == 0) and not idx%time_step == 0:
        custom_labels.append(df.index[idx].strftime('\n%d-%b'))
ax.set_xticks(custom_ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(custom_labels, rotation=0)

plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot_labels2]